# Pulling records from MySQL Db using Laravel 5.1 Pagination

Tags: mysql, if-statement, pagination, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

[image]Someone please help me! How Do I render the records of a DB using pagination? When I tried using this code based on the tutorial I'm using I'm getting this error below. I'd thought the results is a method in Paginate class.

```
<div id="questions">
        <h2>Unsolved Questions</h2>
        @if(!$questions->results)
            <p>No questions have been asked</p>

        @else{
            <ul>
                @foreach($questions->results as $question)
                    <li>{!! e($question->question) !!}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>

            {!! $questions->links !!}
        }   

        @endif
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from ur controller e.g

    $question_model = Questions::where('answer_count','=','0')->orderby('created_at','desc')->paginate(5);

in ur front end for pagination

{!! $question_model->render() !!}
```

Comment: How do I append a user to every question? I'm using this code but not working?<ul>
    @foreach($questions as $question)
     <li>{!! e(str_limit($question->questions, 35)) !!} by {!! $question->users->username !!}</li>
    @endforeach
   </ul>

Comment: it depends upon ur table structure if u have users column in question then fine if its id of user then from joining tables make a single query and pass ...how are you making your query code?

Answer (score 0):

This is the resolve to the question I posted as a response comment to @ujwal dhakal. What I wanted is to append the username of the user that asks a question.

The first thing I did is to add the user collection to the `index.blade.php` view of the question, then iterate through it and pick the username that matches the username of the Auth user that posted the question.

```
@if(!count($questions) > 0)
                <p>No questions have been asked</p>

            @else
                <ul>
                    @foreach($questions as $question)
                        <li>{!! e(str_limit($question->questions, 35)) !!} by 

                            @if(count($users) > 0)
                                @foreach($users as $user)
                                    @if($user->id === $question->userid)
                                        {!! $user->username !!}
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>

                {!! $questions->render() !!}    

            @endif
```